# Laravel route is not getting registered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to create a logout functionality for my Laravel application.

This is my web.php file.

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('/allout', function () {
    return view('login');
});

**Route::get('/logout',function() {
    return "Hi there!";
});**

Route::post('login',[ userController::class,'login']);

Route::get('/',[ ProductController::class,'index']);

Route::get("/detail/{id}",[ProductController::class,'detail']);

Route::post("add_to_cart",[ProductController::class,'addToCart']);
```

And this is where I use the logout route.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Cart({{$total}})</a></li>
        @if(Session::has('user'))
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              {{Session::get('user')['name']}}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              **<a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>**
              {{-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> --}}
            </div>
          </li>
        @else
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        @endif
    </ul>
```

Whenever,I click on the logout dropdown,I get a 404 Not Found error.

I tried

```
 php artisan route:list
```

Got this,

```
    +--------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                 | Name                        | Action                                                     | Middleware                               |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                   | generated::q3N5ckXsde31bkdL | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index               | web                                      |
|        | POST     | add_to_cart         | generated::Kyl3tZiVLjWliGjF | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@addToCart           | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user            | generated::ElNv5GzTAuZ5kHEz | Closure                                                    | api                                      |
|        |          |                     |                             |                                                            | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum |
|        | GET|HEAD | detail/{id}         | generated::kCVhFcAoBMqOBHy5 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@detail              | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD | login               | generated::pGgQjGlbLpvdo4uu | Closure                                                    | web                                      |
|        | POST     | login               | generated::th4afSgvm2atNrCq | App\Http\Controllers\userController@login                  | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD | sanctum/csrf-cookie | generated::QsL6w6jiRisGeEk4 | Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController@show | web                                      |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` (or `php artisan route:cache`)

Comment: This command worked for me!Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Like your login, logout should have related controller and in laravel login/logout support only POST method. Your logout link should be in a form with method POST and @csrf.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <x-dropdown-link :href="route('logout')"
                                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                            this.closest('form').submit();">
                            {{ __('Log Out') }}
                        </x-dropdown-link>
                    </form>
```

and route should be something like this:

```
Route::post('/logout', function () {
    return view('login');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('logout');
```